# "Enable SSL Verification" option does not stay checked in Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have been fiddling around with conda settings for about 3 days now, as my primary goal is simply to use various python packages in a Jupyter Notebook. Because I was having issues downloading some packages, I had run ssl_verify false in an effort to download the packages.

Having been unsuccessful, I attempted unchecking the "Enable SSL Verification" option in the "Preferences" of Anaconda Navigator. This didn't seem to change anything, except for that now every time I open preferences the box remains unchecked, and when I check the box and hit "apply" my cursor moves to the area directly to the left of the checkbox and there is a weird image that is an orange circle with a "!" and it opens an incomplete text box saying "invalid Anaconda URL." After closing the preferences window and re-opening, I find the "Enable SSL Verification" box still unchecked, and I want to be sure that SSL verification is enabled.

This is clearly a bug with Anaconda Navigator and I'm wondering if anybody else has experienced this, and whether there is a way to confirm SSL Verification stays enabled.

Comment: This seems more like a question about tools than about programming.

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1456 answered my question. I was running "conda config --set ssl_verify True", without success. However, running anaconda config --set ssl_verify True fixed the issue